# Условное форматирование в Google Таблицах на основе значений разных ячеек

Tags: google-spreadsheet, format, formula

Я использую Google Sheets для ежедневного сбора статистики. Мне нужно изменить цвет фона ячейек в диапазоне A2:H на основе значениий других ячеек: =G1; M2 или N2 или O2 или P2 или Q2 или R2 или S2 или T2 или U2 или V2 или W2 или X2 или Y2 или Z2; и последнее G2:G если False;

Смысл всех этих манипуляций: в таблице указывают штрафы пользователей и дают 3 дня на рассмотрение. В ячейке G1 формула =Today()-3; для проверки актульности даты для штрафа. В ячейках от M2 до Z2 номера штрафов, если хоть с одним из них совпадает значение в таблице и дата подходит и в диапазоне G2:G стоит флажок False то строка закрашивает красным. После обработки штрафа администратор ставит флажок на True и выделение исчезает.

Вот ссылка на тестовую версию таблицы: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rn03GQfde0V6L39epOf9KiBrw9k2uRNNlcsDC7jjh8M/edit#gid=425680271

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Формат-Условное форматирование-Правила условного форматирования-Ваша формула`

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЕТЕСЛИ($M$2:$Z$2;$D2);И($A2=$G$1;$G2=ЛОЖЬ))
=IF(COUNTIF($M$2:$Z$2;$D2);AND($A2=$G$1;$G2=FALSE))
```

Указать диапазон, к которому применяется форматирование. Задать формат.

Можно  все условия объединить в функции `И (AND)`, но `ЕСЛИ (IF)` помогает обрезать лишние проверки. Замена `И (AND)` на `ЕСЛИ (IF)` еще немного ускорит вычисления.